# List to Array : Row, Column Indices of Selected Cells in Datagrid

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview

I have list of selected cells, I want them to be converted to array so that I can save it.
I am converting list in an array so that I can get indices of all selected cells (column wise in a row) so that I can retrieve later to fill same cells.

Problem is since cells can be selected in random way i.e I can select row 1 column 1,2,3,7,8,9 leaving column 4,5,6 unselected. As soon as I encounter unselected indices I get "**The Index was out of range**"  error.
Same error occur if I select some thing in middle of data grid i.e not selecting column at start like column 1,2,3 but selecting row 5 column 5,6,7.

May be some one can help in this or may be point to some other efficient way of doing same task.

```
List<DataGridViewCell> selectedCells = new List<DataGridViewCell>();

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (selectedCells.Contains(cell) ) selectedCells .Remove(cell);
    else selectedCells .Add(cell);
    cell.Style.BackColor = selectedCells .Contains(cell) ? Color.Pink : Color.White;
}

private void buttonSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string [,] selectedcellsArray = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        while (j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
        {
            selectedcellsArray[i, j] = selectedCells[j].ColumnIndex.ToString();
            j++;
        }

        j = 0;
        i++; //next row
    } 
    //some more code
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `selectedCells`, an empty list, instead of `row`?

Comment: @juharr selectedCells is not empty list, I have added code for your consideration

Comment: The problem here is that `j` is based on the column count, but you're using it to index into `selectedCells`.  I'm really not clear on what you are trying to put into `selectedcellsArray`.  How do you plan to use `selectedcellsArray`? Or can you give an example values for `selectedCells` and what should end up in `selectedcellsArray`?

Comment: @juharr I am trying to get indices (col,row) of selected cells in array so that I can save them and later I can retreive indices and exactly fill color/highlight those cells which were color filled/selected before saving.

Comment: In that case shouldn't `selectedcellsArray` be a `bool[,]` to indicate which cells are selected?  Maybe you could show how you plan to use `selectedcellsArray`?

Comment: I have added pic for explanation, I am trying to save indices of selected cells which I have in list selectedCells, so that I can later retrieve exact position of these cells and again color them. If I wouldn't have indices/position then how can I fill these exact same cells later? May be you can advise better.

Comment: Do you need to iterate over each selected cell to set the color, or over all cells to set the colors?  If just the selected then the `List<DataGridViewCell>` should be all that you need.  If you iterate all of them then a `bool[,]` would make more sense.

Comment: I would be iterating each selected cells to set the color not all of them .

Comment: In that case I don't see why you'd need a 2D array that is the size of the grid.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I was not sure about my idea being efficient, that is why I also asked if there is some other efficient way of doing same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you'd be better off with a `bool[,]` instead.

```
private void buttonSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool [,] cellIsSelected = new bool[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
    foreach(var selectedCell in selectedCells)
    {
        cellIsSelected[selectedCell.RowIndex,selectedCell.ColumnIndex] = true;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            //determine if the cell at postion i,j is selected
            if(cellIsSelected[i,j])
            {
                //It is selected.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if that works you'd be better off just keeping track of that instead of a list of the selected cells (unless you use them somewhere else).  Also this would assume that `dataGridView` has a set number of rows and columns.

```
bool[,] cellIsSelected = new bool[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    cellIsSelected[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] = !cellIsSelected[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex];
    cell.Style.BackColor = cellIsSelected[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] ? Color.Pink : Color.White;
}
```